# Copying a folder with contents without knowing the full path to the folder to another folder

Tags: powershell, cmd

Is this possible using powershell or cmd? I only know the possibility to copy folder knowing the full path to the folder to be copied.

We assume that I want to copy to  C:\copy the examp1, examp2, examp3 folders from the path

```
for examp1 C:\Users\Downloads\path1
for examp2 C:\Users\Downloads\path2
for examp3 C:\Users\Downloads\path3
```

but I don't know the exact name in place of the path1 and so on.

edit:
in general, all the folders that are to be copied (examp1,examp2,examp3 and so on) have a path which is

```
C:\Users\Downloads\2020random\examp1
C:\Users\Downloads\2021random\examp2
```

and so on.
but there are also folders in the

```
C:\Users\Downloads
```

which I don't want to copy and which also have a path, for example

```
C:\Users\Downloads\202020random\exampnottocopy.
```

to sum up, I have a path:

```
C:\Users\Downloads
```

which in turn contains various folders that may start with

```
2020random
2020random
.
.
.
2021random
2021random
```

and in turn they contain the folders I want to copy - I have a complete list of folders I want to copy.
and it is for example:

```
C:\Users\Downloads\2020random\examp1

C:\Users\Downloads\2021random\examp2

C:\Users\Downloads\2021random\examp3
```

and so on.

The difficulty is that not every folder in the location

```
C:\Users\Downloads\2020random
.
.
.
C:\Users\Downloads\2021random
```

contains a folder that is in my list - so I don't want to copy everything that is in the location I am copying from and that the full path to the copied folders is not known.

Comment: Do you know of an approximate name?

Comment: so for example a folder with the name path for examp1 starts with 2020 and then there is a random string of characters, for examp2 it is a name starting with 2020 and again a random string of characters, for examp3 the folder path starts with e.g. 2021 and so on.  In general, I have to copy 500 folders with content for which the last part of the path is different.

Comment: And `Copy-Item path\to\folders\2020* path\to\destination` isn't working?

Comment: But I don't want to copy all the content from the path directory (path\to\folders\2020), only the folders indicated by a specific name( examp1,examp2,examp3 and so on). your command would copy everything from this folder.

Comment: Sorry, I must be misunderstanding your previous comment, didn't you just say the first two folders were named `2020[somerandomstuff]`?

Comment: So you want something like this?
`Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Downloads\20* -Directory | Copy-Item -Destination "yourPath"`

Comment: in general, all the folders that are to be copied (examp1,examp2,examp3 and so on) have have a path which is C:\Users\Downloads\202020random\examp1 , C:\Users\Downloads\2021random\examp2 and so on. but there are also folders in the C:\Users\Downloads which I don't want to copy and which also have a path, for example C:\Users\Downloads\202020random\exampnottocopy.

Comment: And how are they named?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not defined - there are many of them and they have similar names to the ones to be copied. Only the folders to be copied are defined.

Comment: And the files which are in these folders? Do they have a specific name or something that we can work with?

Comment: The files which are in the folder are to be copied together with fodlers (I want the end result to be copying all specified (specific, not all from the location) folders with contents to the defined location) Generally the problem is that I have a list of folders which I want to copy but their exact path is not known - this is the element which causes problems.  Is it possible to do this at all or should the complete path of the folders to be copied always be known?

Comment: Its definitely possible, and can be fair easily accomplished. We are just having trouble understanding what you are looking for. So, do all the folders you want copied start with just **20**?

Comment: I edited description, please check.

Comment: Ok, so you have a list of folders you want to copy, please provide a bit more information, how does the list look like?

Comment: for example: examp1, examp2, examp3, examp100, examp201, examp900 as I wrote in description.

Comment: Try this, is that what you expect.

`$foldersyouwant = Get-Content -Path "yourPath"`

`Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Downloads\ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -in $foldersyouwant}`

Comment: Can you explain step by step how to use it in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have your folders you'd like to copy in a textfile, you can try this.

Load the content of your textfile into the variable `$foldersyouwant`

```
$foldersyouwant = Get-Content -Path "yourPath"
```

Then you can simply output that data by using this command here

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Downloads\ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -in $foldersyouwant}
```

Does it show your expected folders?

Yes, then you can add another pipe and do the magic

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Downloads\ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -in $foldersyouwant} | Copy-Item -Destination "yourDestination"
```

Comment: Is it possible to use robocopy here? Unfortunately the path of the copied files is too long for the Copy-Item command

Comment: @Oddityspace Sure, but i don't think that the length of the path is too long. Do you get any error?

Comment: the error occurs because I am also recursively copying files in a folder (I added the -recurse option) - these files have quite long names - and as a result files with too long names cannot be copied. error message: Copy-Item : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 ch aracters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Comment: Are you able to present a solution using the robocopy command?